# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property VS is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, tsconfig

What is going on with this typescript:

```js
         const [first, ...arrTrunc] = liveMenu;
         const newArr = arrTrunc;

         newArr[0].name = first.name || "profile";
         // Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property to newArr
```

ok so I try this:

```js
         const [first, ...arrTrunc] = liveMenu;
         let newArr = arrTrunc;

         newArr[0].name = first.name || "profile";
         // Error: newArr is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead
```

How can it be an error both ways? If you have encountered this and figured out a solution please post it here thanks.

I would rather not set my TS config to:

```json
      "prefer-const": "off"
```

Comment: Works fine for me . Which version of TS ?

Comment: "typescript": "^4.8.2"